# Access a server side datatable in an observe event

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a modal that diplays text dynamically. Below is a reprex of what I'm thinking. My actual example I am creating a datatable based on reactive user input and interacting with a sql database so creating it in global environment is not desirable. Is there an easy way I can access the dataframe within the randerDataTable? My code below creates an error because table is not a dataframe object. I know renderDataTable does not create a dataframe, rather it creates an html table. Can I still access the data similiarly to a dataframe or parse it into a dataframe?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable({

t <- data.frame(
      x = rep(c('dog', 'cat', 'pig'),5),
      y = rnorm(15),
      z = rnorm(15)
    )

      DT::datatable(t, rownames=F, selection = 'none', options = list('tipl')) %>%
        formatStyle(3, cursor = 'pointer')})
    
    #Display the value of the cell in a modal
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_clicked, {
      info = input$table_cell_clicked
      # do nothing if not clicked yet, or the clicked cell is not in the 1st column
      if (is.null(info$value) || info$col != 2) return()
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = paste("The animal you selected is:", table$x[info$row]), #creates an error because table is not a df object. Would like to do something like this though.
        paste("The value of the cell is:", info$value),
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a global variable for this :

```r
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    global_table <- NULL
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      
      global_table <<- data.frame(
        x = rep(c('dog', 'cat', 'pig'),5),
        y = rnorm(15),
        z = rnorm(15)
      )
      
      DT::datatable(global_table, rownames=F, selection = 'none', options = list('tipl')) %>%
        formatStyle(3, cursor = 'pointer')})
    
    #Display the value of the cell in a modal
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_clicked,{
      info = input$table_cell_clicked
      warning(info$row )
      # do nothing if not clicked yet, or the clicked cell is not in the 1st column
      if (is.null(info$value) || info$col != 0) return()
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = paste("The animal you selected is:", global_table$x[info$row]),
        paste("The value of the cell is:", info$value),
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
    })
  }
```

But it's more elegant to use a `reactive` to compute the data

```r
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    reactive_table <- reactive(
      data.frame(
        x = rep(c('dog', 'cat', 'pig'),5),
        y = rnorm(15),
        z = rnorm(15)
      ))
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(reactive_table(), rownames=F, selection = 'none', 
                    options = list('tipl')) %>%
        formatStyle(3, cursor = 'pointer')})
    
    #Display the value of the cell in a modal
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_clicked,{
      info = input$table_cell_clicked
      warning(info$row )
      # do nothing if not clicked yet, or the clicked cell is not in the 1st column
      if (is.null(info$value) || info$col != 0) return()
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = paste("The animal you selected is:", reactive_table()$x[info$row]),
        paste("The value of the cell is:", info$value),
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
    })
  }
```